# Is WolframAlpha doing Math wrong?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I just tried to solve the following equation with WolframAlpha and got some very weird results:

[\sum_{i=1}^{x}x^2*i = 318338237039211050000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Ik7.png)

[image]

---

1. [WolframAlpha tells me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi=1%7D%5E%7Bx%7Dx%5E2*i%20=%20318338237039211050000), one of the real solutions is x = 158847.000000000;
2. [It also tells me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=158847.000000000+%3D+158847) that (of course) 158847.000000000 = 158847;
3. [WA then tells me](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7B158847.000000000%7D158847.000000000%5E2*i+%3D+318338237039211050000), that the equation using x=158847.000000000 is true;
4. [But the same equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7B158847%7D158847%5E2*i+%3D+318338237039211050000) using x=158847 is false.

---

Shouldn't be 3) and 4) both true? Can anyone explain these results to me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the nature of comparisons for floating point equality. For example, there is no fixed precision decimal representation for `1/3` such that `(3 * 1/3) = 1` is true. And you can make `(2/3 + 1/3) = 1` be true *or* `(1/3 + 1/3) = 2/3` be true but not both. See [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: here is a good video explaining what david is saying:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Comment: I understand this for 1/3, but I don't see the difficulties in storing .0 as binary floating point

Comment: There is nothing special about where the decimal point is. Numbers on one side of the decimal point are not different from numbers on the other side of the decimal point.

Comment: But where are the rounding errors with this number. Isn't 1.00110110001111111_2×2^17 the exact floating point representation of it? And since there is this exact representation, shouldn't there be no rounding errors?

Comment: The problem is more likely with 31833823703921105000.

Comment: So this number is converted to floating point, too? Which would be 1.0001010000011101010010011011111101010111101001000101111101000001_2×2^68. So what this means then is, that WolframAlpha does the calculation with a floating point precision less than 68 bits, right?

Comment: It's dangerous to guess, but it's a reasonable inference that it does so in at least some cases.

Comment: Hm. But this seems unusual to me. Because usually WolframAlpha seems to be able to do calculations with an arbitrary high precision.

Comment: @x_puma_x Making the reason question -- why doesn't it in this particular case?